# What is the diffrent between h264 & h264+

Tags: h.264, rtsp, rtp, rfc, openh264

I have looking on [rfc of h264](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984), and looking the diffrent between h264 and h264+ ,not in the context of compression quality but how the packets are configured in RTP stream.

Is h264+ has another NAL type number (SPS,PPS,IDR etc.) is there any NAL type that configure at h264+ and not configure in h264?

I saw the in h264+ SPS and PPS and IDR send very rarely compared to h264 , why is that?

Answer (score 0):

h264+ seems to be only a commercial denomination. There is no specification about this.